# How can I convert the result of Text.Printf to String?

Tags: string, haskell, return, printf

The result of Text.Printf is a variable of type PrintfType.

Is there a way to convert this result to String?

I want something like that: convertToString :: PrintfType -> String

I've searched everywhere but I can't find anything.

Comment: what about [`printf`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Text-Printf.html#v:printf) (the function ... ) - btw: `PrintfType` is no type - it's a class

Comment: This is the function I am talking about. It takes a formatted String an an input and returns a PrintfType. My problem is that I want to convert that PrintfType to a String. I don't understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: it will give you a string if you ask it to - try: `printf "%d" 55 :: String` - `String ~ [Char]` is an instance of `PrintfType`

Comment: It works, but it gives me an array of chars, not a String. I really need it to be a String. Thank you for that workaround.

Comment: ... well a `String` *is* a list of `Char` (not an array) ... but let me guess: you are using Hugs?

Comment: No, I am not using Hugs (I don't really know what this is). Yes, a String is a list of Char, not an array. My bad.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109473/discussion-between-xor-ntg-and-carsten).

Comment: just a wild guess (Hugs is an older Haskell implementation and I thought it might give the type as `[Char]`) - let me give you an advice on your way: forget anything about types and classes you might bring along from C# - they will hurt your understanding for the most parts

Comment: Yes, I already feel that. I will try now to convert [Char] to String

Comment: look you don't have to convert anything - `String` is just a type-synonym for `[Char]` ... they are literally the same in Haskell - it's as if you would write `using MyString = System.IEnumerable<System.Char>;` in C#

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you respectfully!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The result of Text.Printf is a variable of type PrintfType.

No.  `PrintfType`  is a constraint on the type, not a type itself.  Notice the instances of `PrintfType` provided by `module Text.Printf` are:

```
IsChar c => PrintfType [c]
(~) * a () => PrintfType (IO a)
(PrintfArg a, PrintfType r) => PrintfType (a -> r)
```

> Is there a way to convert this result to String?

No conversion necessary, `String ~ [Char]` and there exists an instance `IsChar Char`.  Thus, the constraint of `PrintfType String` is satisfied.

> I want something like that: convertToString :: PrintfType -> String

That makes no sense since you're using `PrintfType` as a Type instead of a constraint.